# Jenkins / Apache Reverse Proxy Error

Tags: apache, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I am running into an issue that seems to be fairly common based off of my searches, however I've followed all the instructions and/or fixes I've run into but none have worked for me so I'm asking this hoping someone can guide me in the right direction.

I have Jenkins 1.644 installed on OS X 10.11.2 from Homebrew.  I followed [these](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/installing-jenkins-osx-yosemite.html) instructions on how to install and get it setup inside OS X Server 5.0.15 Websites (I believe this version of OS X server is running Apache 2.4.16.

The problem:  When I connect to the manage console in Jenkins, I get the error message "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken." and a link to [this jenkins doc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache).

Hitting http://127.0.0.1:8080/manage does not produce the error.

I have added the proxy settings to my virtual host file like so:

```
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://jenkins.exampledomain.com/

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

When I do the test curl:

```
curl -iLk -e https://jenkins.exampledomain.com/manage \
   https://jenkins.exampledomain.com/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test
```

I get the following results:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 06:30:57 GMT
Server: Jetty(winstone-2.9)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: https://jenkins.exampledomain.com/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/https%3A%2F%2Fjenkins.exampledomain.com%2Fmanage/
Content-Length: 0
MS-Author-Via: DAV

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 06:30:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/0.9.8zg
Content-Length: 325
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/https://jenkins.exampledomain.com/manage/ was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Clearly that address is on this server because I can enter the management console by going to the correct address.

I'm stuck... Apache configuration is not my strong point.  I'm looking for any help.

**--EDIT More Info--**

Adding the full virtual host file from the /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites directory for further detail.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:34543>
    ServerName https://jenkins.exampledomain.com:443
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/jenkins.exampledomain.com"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php default.html
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combinedvhost
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCipherSuite "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
        SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/certificates/machine.local.certCA1FileLocation.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/certificates/machine.local.certCA2FileLocation.key.pem"
        SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/certificates/machine.local.certCA3FileLocation.chain.pem"
        SSLProxyProtocol -ALL +TLSv1
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/jenkins.exampledomain.com">
        Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            DAV Off
        </IfModule>
        <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
            Require all denied
            ErrorDocument 403 /customerror/websitesoff403.html
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://jenkins.exampledomain.com/

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
</VirtualHost>
```

**--EDIT 2 Another Finding--**

I have noticed by attempting to curl to the 'not found' url above that indeed the server is reporting it not found.  If I hit https://jenkins.exampledomain.com/manage/ I will get a 404.  However, if I leave off the trailing /, it works.  https://jenkins.exampledomain.com/manage is successful.  Hopefully this means something to someone!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Jenkins complain that my reverse proxy setup is broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161854/why-does-jenkins-complain-that-my-reverse-proxy-setup-is-broken)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I was having the same problem with the error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/https%3A%2F%2Fbuild.scopeitconsulting.com%2Fmanage/. Reason:

http://build.domain.com/manage vs. https://build.domain.com/manage
```

I was able to solve my problem by including the two lines from the author's question:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

So here is my relevant section from a working ssl.conf configuration in case it helps anybody.  I am running Jenkins on port 8080 at the root context with http but reverse proxying it behind Apache enforcing https.

```
ProxyPass               / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse        / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse        / http://build.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse        / https://build.domain.com/
ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPreserveHost       On
AllowEncodedSlashes     NoDecode
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

I hope this helps somebody who like me has spent way too much time trying to find a working configuration to resolve the error.

Comment: Sorry, but where did you include those two lines? I don't really understand.

Comment: They would be added to your Apache configuration file.

Comment: Do you need in this case to Listen on port 80 or this is not mandatory ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below to catalina.properties file. Updating Apache configuration itself is not sufficient.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```