# Why does Jenkins say my reverse proxy setup is broken?

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins 2.32.2 on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and configured Apache proxy as described [on their wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache).

I changed these lines in `/etc/default/jenkins`:

```
HTTP_PORT=8380

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --prefix=/jenkins"
```

With these, I can access Jenkins at http://myhost:8380/jenkins/

For the proxy, I created the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/jenkins.conf` with this content:

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://myhost:8380/jenkins nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://myhost:8380/jenkins
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# Local reverse proxy authorization override
# Most unix distribution deny proxy by default (ie /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf in Ubuntu)
<Proxy http://myhost:8380/jenkins*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Then I enabled the configuration (with `sudo a2enconf jenkins`) and restarted Apache. Now I can access Jenkins at http://myhost/jenkins.

In principle it's OK, but in the "Manage Jenkins" page I get a message saying *"It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken."* with a link to [a wiki page with possible solutions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+says+my+reverse+proxy+setup+is+broken?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true#addcomment).

One of the suggestions was to try this for diagnosis:

```
curl -iL -e http://myhost/jenkins/manage http://myhost/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test
```

This is the output:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 07:01:00 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
X-Hudson: 1.395
X-Jenkins: 2.32.2
X-Jenkins-Session: 7b3e99ac
X-You-Are-Authenticated-As: anonymous
X-You-Are-In-Group: 
X-Required-Permission: hudson.model.Hudson.Read
X-Permission-Implied-By: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
X-Permission-Implied-By: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
Content-Length: 973
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.34f83688=1rkbqf12ykw0w1clnm0l7cc9l6;Path=/jenkins;HttpOnly

<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2FadministrativeMonitor%2Fhudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor%2Ftest'/><script>window.location.replace('/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2FadministrativeMonitor%2Fhudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor%2Ftest');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

Is that anonymous/403 a problem? In Jenkins, I get the error while being logged in.

I also checked "Jenkins Location / Jenkins URL" in settings, and it's OK: http://myhost/jenkins/

Comment: did you ever solve it?

Comment: @peedee, I didn't solve it yet. I didn't try anymore, I'm just using it like that. I believe this could be a bug in Jenkins and maybe I should report it.

Comment: I am running multiple jenkins server, I getting similar error on version 2.46.3. I am able to resolve is by addtion below line in JENKINS_HOME/config.xml

  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors>
    <string>hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor</string>
  </disabledAdministrativeMonitors>

Comment: @Atul N you are not solving it, you are disabling it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Jenkins complain that my reverse proxy setup is broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161854/why-does-jenkins-complain-that-my-reverse-proxy-setup-is-broken)

Comment: Adding `<disabledAdministrativeMonitors> <string>hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor</string> </disabledAdministrativeMonitors>` to `JENKINS_HOME/config.xml` does not help on Jenkins 2.261, running on Windows (as a service), with no reverse proxy, using HTTPS and a self-signed cert, NetBIOS name rather than FQDN.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem.

You need to look at /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log

In my case I had

```
WARNING h.d.ReverseProxySetupMonitor#getTestForReverseProxySetup: http://myhost/manage vs. https:%2F%2Fmyhost%2Fmanage
```

The trick is that both url should be the same. As can be seen, in my case, there was 2 problems:

the encoding of the slash, this has been sorted by adding **nocanon** at the end of **ProxyPass**.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8083/ nocanon
```

the https became http, this has been sorted by adding the following line

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
```