# Jenkins It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.

Tags: jenkins, proxy

This problem has already been posted, I just have one question.

The suggestion from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161854/why-jenkins-complains-reserve-proxy-setup-is-broken) was to:

> Make sure the Jenkins URL configured in the System Configuration
>   matches the URL you're using to access Jenkins.

To reach the System Configuration:

```
Go to your Jenkins page
Click Manage Jenkins
Click Configure System
Scroll to Jenkins Location and find Jenkins URL.
```

**Ensure that port value matches with the port value set in the  section of the jenkins.xml file located in the Jenkins folder on your machine.**

I looked at the URL from the Configuration System, and I opened my jenkins.xml. But I don´t see any URL in my jenkins.xml file, where I should add it? in any place like `<argument>http://jenkins.subdomain.com/</argument>` ?

My Jenkins File is:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>2.107.2</version>
  <installState>
    <isSetupComplete>true</isSetupComplete>
    <name>RUNNING</name>
  </installState>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
  </authorizationStrategy>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
    <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
    <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
  </securityRealm>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  <projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
  <jdks/>
  <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  <myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
  <clouds/>
  <quietPeriod>5</quietPeriod>
  <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
  <views>
 <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>all</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
  <primaryView>all</primaryView>
  <slaveAgentPort>-1</slaveAgentPort>
  <disabledAgentProtocols>
    <string>JNLP-connect</string>
    <string>JNLP2-connect</string>
  </disabledAgentProtocols>
  <label></label>
<crumbIssuer class="hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer">
    <excludeClientIPFromCrumb>false</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>
  </crumbIssuer>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <globalNodeProperties>
    <hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
      <envVars serialization="custom">
        <unserializable-parents/>
        <tree-map>
          <default>
            <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
          </default>
          <int>1</int>
          <string>ACR_LOGINSERVER</string>
          <string>containerregistryah.azurecr.io</string>
           </tree-map>
      </envVars>
    </hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty>
  </globalNodeProperties>
</hudson>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Jenkins complain that my reverse proxy setup is broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161854/why-does-jenkins-complain-that-my-reverse-proxy-setup-is-broken)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Configuration should have nocanon for ProxyPass. If SSL is enabled X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-Port must be set.

```
ProxyPass               / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
AllowEncodedSlashes     NoDecode
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

You need to add below to catalina.properties file in Tomcat. Updating Apache configuration itself is not sufficient.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```